# Replicate cell in excel

Tags: excel, cell, replicate

Does anyone know if there is a way to replicate a cell exactly in excel, so that it has both the same value and same format? So that if the format of the 'parent' cell changes (through conditional formatting) then the replicated cell also changes format.

Thanks in advance

Comment: what technology are you using? Just excel? Would macro work for that? please elaborate your question, as it is not clear where you are working with Excel.

Comment: Sorry. Yeah just standard excel (2007 version)

Comment: You could just apply the same conditional formatting to the 2nd cell.

Comment: Depending on exactly what you need to do with this "replica", you could try the Camera tool (or "paste picture link" in xl2007).

Comment: Thanks Tim, this does work and is perhaps the best I'm going to get, but the values in the pasted cells are very hard to read. Is this a problem you know of when using this and if so do you know of any hints or tips to get the resolution better on the new cells? Thanks

Comment: And thanks to you Doug to, but I want the new cell to automatically change to the same format as the original cell should the original cell change format so that wouldn't work in this case

Comment: @user - not sure I'm seeing the issue, unless I shrink the size of the pasted link.

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume the original cell is A1.

The simplest way would be to set the new cell `=a1`. To copy the conditional formatting, Select the original cell, a1, and select the Format Painter (on the clipboard sub-menu; looks like a paintbrush on a diagonal). (The icon will change to a paintbrush.) Then click on the new cell.

I tried this out for several types of Conditional Formatting, and it works well for the Conditional Formatting -> Highlight Cell Rules (Say, Greater than nn).

It also works well for ranges like Top/Bottom Rules or Color Scales, but you will need to copy the entire range (it won't work if you're copying a single cell because the range doesn't make sense).

Comment: Thanks rajah, this would work perfectly as a one-off but unless I have misunderstood you and done something wrong the new cell doesn't change format when the original cell changes format. I wanted the cells linked so that if the original cell changes value or changes format then the new cell also changes to the same value and format

Comment: Got it. The accepted answer at http://superuser.com/questions/98755/excel-copy-cell-formatting-in-equation says you can't do it without VBA. Aaron Blood's answer at http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=42136 gives the VBA.

Comment: Thanks rajah. Seems strange that there isn't an easy way of doing this since after searching for how to do this online it seems a few people have asked the same thing. If anyone from microsoft is reading maybe one for the next version...